# Are there any books on the Reti-Spielmann attack (1. e4 e6 2. g3)?

Tags: books, french-defense

I tried looking for books on this online but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Searching Reti Spielmann on google books gives a few results.

Comment: Do you have any links? I found books on Reti and Spielmann but nothing on this specific variation.